# Car won't start but battery is new

Tags: opel

I have a 2000 Opel corsa b and I stalled it today, the lights started flickering and clicking, I tried to start it about 15 minutes after this but it won't start and lights keep flickering and clicking, it can't be the battery because I changed it, the car has been sitting for about 2 months but I start it daily,  I have no insurance and so I can't drive it, if any one has any ideas, please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may have just flattened the battery due to starting it daily and not letting it run long enough to put charge back in the battery, you need to put the battery on a charger to charge it back up.

It is also possible that your alternator is not charging the battery when the engine is running.  The next time you start the engine, check the battery voltage while the engine is running.  If the alternator is OK, the voltage should be 13.8 - 14.4 volts.

Another possibility is that your battery connections are not clean and tight causing a bad connection.

Comment: Thanks HandyHowie I don't have a meter but I am going to get one, do you measure the voltage from the connections on the battery or on the ends of the cables

Comment: Does the battery charge if the car isn't moving

Comment: Push the test probes onto the battery terminal posts (the metal posts that are part of the battery)

Comment: The battery should charge even when the car is not moving.  Starting the engine takes a lot of power from the battery, so you may have to leave the engine running for 15 to 20 minutes to put the same amount of electricity back into the battery.

Comment: Thank you,  I managed to start it after disconnecting and re connecting the battery and it started, thank you for all the information, if i have any other questions atleast i have a very down to earth and knowlegable person, thanks again

Comment: @Michael  you can mark the question as answered and upvote handyhowie to reward him for assisting you!  Welcome to stack exchange.  You can also take the tour and see how this site works by clicking here.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour   Cheers!